# Push operation has failed. See the PushResult for details error in while pushing to Azure Portal Easy tables

Tags: azure, xamarin.android

I'm working with Microsoft [Azure portal offline sync](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/web-services/sync/azure-mobile-apps/) using Xamarin Android. And I created an Easy Table in Azure portal and I tried to synchronize data with the Azure Mobile Apps instance with following line of code.

```
await userData.PullAsync("userdata", userData.CreateQuery());
                await Client.SyncContext.PushAsync();
```

While running the application I got the exception like **Push operation has failed. See the PushResult for details** and data is not synchronizing with Azure.

Can anybody help me to fix this!

Thanks!!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? (I have the same issue - and strangely I think this used to work.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "userdata" which I have given as a parameter to PullAsync() didn't match with Azure's EasyTable. Fixed it by giving the same name to the EasyTable name in azure portal.

Hope It helps for you also! :)

Comment: how does changes made in pullasync solves a push error?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that none of your fields are empty if your database does not allow for nulls

Answer (score 0):

This error can happen because of 2 reasons(dont know the number is above 2):

1. you are trying to push fields which are (empty/null/invalid symbol) and eazy tables/databases does not usually support null values.
2. you are trying to push fields which is not in database schema.